# google sign in flutter web integration

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a problem integrating the google sign in web package in flutter web framework.
I want to retrieve the idToken but I can't.

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    clientId:  'my client id'
    signInOption: SignInOption.standard,
    scopes: [
      'email',
    ],
  );
     _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged
            .listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) async {
    
          // In mobile, being authenticated means being authorized...
          bool isAuthorized = account != null;
          debugPrint('silentUserLogin account is : $account');
          // However, in the web...
          if (kIsWeb && account != null) {
            isAuthorized = await _googleSignIn.canAccessScopes(scopes);
          }
    
    
          // Now that we know that the user can access the required scopes, the app
          // can call the REST API.
        });
```

in the widget i did this

```
/// Renders a web-only SIGN IN button.
Widget buildSignInButton({HandleSignInFn? onPressed}) {
  return (GoogleSignInPlatform.instance as web.GoogleSignInPlugin)
      .renderButton();
}
```

and i recive this

```
GoogleSignInAccount:{displayName: Brahim CHEBBI, email: brahim.chebbi@esprit.tn, id: 113873915042996649214, photoUrl: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AAcHTtdesTEaIgpxbI0e3jxNnPwkwEe6K_ylHIAea7uDdBfnIg=s96-c, serverAuthCode: null}
```

I don't understand why the serverAuthCode is null and I want to know how I can retrieve the idToken .

Answer (score 1):

I was trying this approach, but then I do use Firebase package and works, try this. Change UI for a simple button and call that function.

1. Use the Firebase method: This will ensure that the user is prompted
   to select an account from their Google account list. To do this, add
   the following code to your signInWithPopup() method:

```dart
if (kIsWeb) {
  final GoogleAuthProvider provider = GoogleAuthProvider()
      .setCustomParameters({'prompt': 'select_account'});
  await _firebaseAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `idToken` from the `GoogleSignInAuthentication` object.

After you have the `GoogleSignInAccount` you can call `account.authentication`

I have modified your example below:

```
_googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged
        .listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) async {   

      bool isAuthorized = account != null;
      debugPrint('silentUserLogin account is : $account');
      
      if (kIsWeb && account != null) {
        isAuthorized = await _googleSignIn.canAccessScopes(scopes);


        // NEW CODE HERE

        final authentication = await account.authentication;
        final idToken = authentication.idToken;

      } 
    });
```